# Django distinct returns more records than count

Tags: django, django-orm

The following shows the distinct count is 2247

```
In [6]: VirtualMachineResources.objects.all().values('machine', 'cluster')
   ...: .distinct().count()                                               
Out[6]: 2247
```

But then when I loop through it, it returned way more than it should:

```
In [4]: a = [] 
   ...: for resource in VirtualMachineResources.objects.all().values('mach
   ...: ine', 'cluster').distinct(): 
   ...:     if resource['cluster']: 
   ...:         a.append(resource['cluster']) 
   ...:          
   ...:                                                                   

In [5]: len(a)                                                            
Out[5]: 96953
```

Given the records have cluster field being empty, when I loop through the queryset, I can see a lot of repeats of the same machine without cluster value, but I would expect only once.

```
for resource in VirtualMachineResources.objects.all().values('machine', 'cluster').distinct(): 
    print(resource['machine'], resource['cluster'])
```

prints...

```
server1
server1
server1
```

It's a postgres database. Any ideas? 
Having a few more digs on google and [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2939) seems related?

UPDATE:
Created a Django issue [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30130#ticket)

Comment: I have seen machine without cluster value keep showing up...

Comment: Its mentioned in the link you provided :  "The problem is that the count method on the QuerySet class is not aware of the _fields field of the ValuesQuerySet subclass. As such, it does the same thing as if values() was not used at all. The attached patch addresses the problem by copying-and-specializing the count method from QuerySet to ValuesQuerySet. If no _fields are present (in the distinct case), the primary key is used as in the original QuerySet count method. The patch is somewhat naive; it may be preferable to refactor the QuerySet count method, but I'm not sure what the preferred s

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom `Manager` and add your own queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a defined `VirtualMachineResources.Meta.ordering` that confuses the ORM as the ordered by columns must appear in the `SELECT` clause when using `DISTINCT`. The ordering happens to be cleared when using `.count()`.

Long storing short, add a `.order_by()` to drop your `Meta.ordering` on the queryset you are iterating over and you should be good to go. There's no good way to generate a `DISTINCT` that excludes ordering fields on Django's ORM yet as that would require a complex subquery pushdown as detailed in [#24218](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24218).

By the way, please avoid Django's ticket tracker as a second tier support channel when you are not receiving a reply to your question as fast as you'd like.